# How to use Chronometer on Android?

Tags: java, android, chronometer

I want to create a countdown of 10 seconds. When countdown finishes calling a function.

```
enter code here
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself?

Comment: I just started with Android, and I have little time with Java.

Comment: Do you want us to write this code for you for free?

Comment: not, 

I'm looking for some kind of tutorial or initiate me helping me with the chronometer. (Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is already an api for just that:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

**Reference:**
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html